Attempting to force msg.sender
I use Forge to test and I believe another error depends on that msg.sender != owner.
So, I have tried to make msg.sender the owner, but my attempts fail.
The target contract is never called so I omit it.
Any idea how to make assign msg.sender a value?
This is the test contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import {Test} from "../lib/forge-std/src/Test.sol";
import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";
import {MsgSender} from "../src/MsgSender.sol";

contract MsgSenderTest is Test {
    MsgSender public msgSender;
    address public owner;

    function setUp() public {
        owner = vm.envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS");
        console.log("Owner Address:", owner);
        msgSender = new MsgSender();
    }

    function test_run() external{
        vm.startPrank(owner);
        console.log("msg.sender:", msg.sender);
        //assert(msg.sender == owner);
        msgSender.run();
        vm.stopPrank();
    }
}

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.26;

import {console} from "../lib/forge-std/src/console.sol";

contract MsgSender {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function run() external view onlyOwner {
        console.log("Owner:", owner);
        console.log("Msg.Sender:", msg.sender);
    }
}

And this is the terminal output:
test/MsgSender.t.sol:MsgSenderTest
  ↪ Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 4.17s (151.64µs CPU time)

Ran 1 test for test/MsgSender.t.sol:MsgSenderTest
[FAIL. Reason: revert: Not the owner] test_run() (gas: 16614)
Logs:
  Owner Address: 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693
  msg.sender: 0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38

Traces:
  [393276] MsgSenderTest::setUp()
    ├─ [0] VM::envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Return] <env var value>
    ├─ [0] console::log("Owner Address:", 0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [326453] → new MsgSender@0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f
    │   └─ ← [Return] 1166 bytes of code
    └─ ← [Stop] 

  [16614] MsgSenderTest::test_run()
    ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0xb04d6a4949fa623629e0ED6bd4Ecb78A8C847693)
    │   └─ ← [Return] 
    ├─ [0] console::log("msg.sender:", DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    ├─ [2600] MsgSender::run() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← [Revert] revert: Not the owner
    └─ ← [Revert] revert: Not the owner


The address that you’re pranking with, will be used as msg.sender in the transaction that you do right after vm.prank(address) or in between vm.startPrank(address) and vm.stopPrank().
In your case, it’s not changed to owner address because you’re directly asserting or logging it within the same function where you’ve started the prank.
So, if you check the value of msg.sender inside the run() function of your MsgSender contract (i.e., you’re calling as msgSender.run() right after the assert statement), then the msg.sender value inside that would be equivalent to the owner address, because the execution of that msgSender.run() function is corresponding to a transaction executed within a prank done by the pranked address (i.e., owner).
Edit:
Since the run() function of your MsgSender contract is having onlyOwner modifier, so you’ve to deploy the MsgSender contract with the same address using which you’re pranking the msgSender.run() function.
For that, you can modify the setUp() function of your MsgSenderTest contract to prank the deployment of the MsgSender contract using the owner address.
function setUp() public {
    owner = vm.envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS");
    console.log("Owner Address:", owner);

    // Deploy MsgSender with owner set as WALLET_ADDRESS
    vm.startPrank(owner);
    msgSender = new MsgSender();
    vm.stopPrank();
}


I tried your suggestion, allowing msgSender.run() to run but I don't get the expected result which is msg.sender == owner. I updated the code above.

That’s because the msg.sender is set as the initial owner address that you initialized in MsgSenderTest contract as vm.envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS").

You can check by logging the same, instead of creating and initializing new owner address in the MsgSender contract. So, just log console.log(vm.envAddress("WALLET_ADDRESS")) in the run() function of the MsgSender contract. It should be equal to the msg.sender.
